# Joining an iPad-hosted game from Android

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to join a Minecraft world from an Android device if the world is hosted on an iPad?  I want to get a Galaxy Tab for my son, but most of his friends use iPads when playing Minecraft together. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "can Minecraft on Android and iOS connect to each other?" or are you talking about actual transfer of saved worlds?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to whether or not Minecraft users on Android and iOS can all inhabit the same worlds simo

Answer (score 7):

Yes, according to the [MinecraftWiki.net](http://minecraftwiki.net):

```
"The multiplayer mode is cross-platform compatible between Android and iOS."
```

Most people have said it works fine but I have heard of a few rare situations where one could not successfully use an Android to connect to iOS. Perhaps it was due to some user error or something else, it's hard to say. Hope this helped.

Comment: The only times I have not been able to connect are due to a network error. Turning the iPad to Airplane mode and back again, as well as totally killing off the Minecraft app on the Android platform resolves this ( at least it does for me)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is perfectly possible as long as they are both connected to the same wifi network. We do this at home all the time. The game is started on the iPad and my Android mobile phone (HTC-One X) can connect and join in the world quite happily.